# Use eigenvectors() from c++ eigen library to calculate only one eigen vector

Tags: c++, eigen, eigenvector

The compute method of Selfadjointeigensolver() method of Eigen library computes the eigen vectors of all the eigen values. I want to make it calculate eigen vector of only one specific eigen value e.g the smallest or the 5th from smallest. Is this possible ?

Comment: Generally, finding the nth eigenvector is as expensive as diagonalizing the matrix, if I remember correctly. Exceptions are the smallest or largest eigenvalues, where a shifted inverse iteration can be used. I am, however, not aware of an implementation within eigen.

Comment: You could compute all Eigenvalues, and manually compute an Eigenvector to a specific Eigenvalue. Or for large sparse matrices, you can have a look at the `ArpackSupport` module (no idea how stable the module is at the moment, it looks like it is entirely undocumented, so you need to check [the source](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/default/unsupported/Eigen/ArpackSupport) for the API)

Comment: @chtz how would i calculate the eigen vector from this eigen value, for a large matrix?

Comment: You'd compute the kernel of `A - lambda*Identity`, e.g., using `FullPivLU`. Not sure if you actually gain anything from that (that's why I'm not posting this as an answer).

Answer (score 1):

If your matrix is real and you are already using Eigen, the simplest is to use [Spectra](https://github.com/yixuan/spectra/), which is a header only library that only requires Eigen. It's a redesign of old Arpack, which uses Arnoldi power iteration to iteratively converge towards extremal eigenvalue/eigenvector pairs. You can ask for "a few" eigenpairs at a time.

If your matrix is complex you have two options. Either you go for [Arpack++](https://github.com/m-reuter/arpackpp) directly which can handle complex matrices but is more tedious to use OR you can insist on Spectra by splitting the matrix into real and imaginary parts as [explained here](http://www.pha.jhu.edu/~neufeld/numerical/lecturenotes11.pdf), but this comes with a large performance penalty. Essentially, if you have a complex `N*N`matrix `A=B+iC` and vector `x=u+iv` you turn the eigenvalue equation `Ax=kx` into `(B+iC)(u+iv)=k(u+iv)`, which can be written as a `2N*2N` problem.

If your matrix is truly large you may want to consider [Slepc](http://slepc.upv.es/).